# Series.Items() Method Returns Zip Instead of Expected Output (Pandas)

Tags: python, pandas, methods, boolean, series

I am attempting to access the index of a series returned by the series.items() method in Pandas.

I was able to successfully do so when the series I generated was the result of a groupby:

```
df = pd.DataFrame( {
     'species': ['dog', 'cat', 'horse', 'dog', 'cat', 'horse'],
     'weight': [44.5, 12.3, 600.2, 37.3, 8.5, 405.9]
     } ) 
       
df.groupby(['species'])['weight'].sum().items()

species
dog          81.8
cat          20.8
horse        1006.1
```

This is the expected output, which allows me to access the index (species) of the series.

When I use the same method .items() on the following series generated with the .any() method, I do not get the same output.

```
df.isna().any().items()
<zip at 0x89529b3100> #The string here is random but approximate to what is seen.
```

I have verified that .any() produces a series through the pandas documentation, and have used the type() function to verify in both cases that each are of the series data type.

I am very confused why the .items() method does not return an output such as:

```
dog        False
cat        False
horse      False
```

I would greatly appreciate any guidance on what error I might be committing or what I am misunderstanding about Boolean series. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you might be mistaken about the use of `.items()`. It is used to return an iterable of name/series tuples that you could perhaps use in a for loop or otherwise.
I recommend playing around with wrapping the result in `list()` to exhaust the iterable, just so you can get a better idea of what is going on:

```
$ list(df.groupby(['species'])['weight'].sum().items())

[('cat', 20.8), ('dog', 81.8), ('horse', 1006.1)]
```

Also, your first block of code is not showing the correct output, which may be confusing you. Rather it is showing the output of `.sum()`, so be careful there.

So to hopefully answer your questions, you have the following:

Viewing sum of weights grouped by species

```
$ df.groupby(['species'])['weight'].sum()

species
cat        20.8
dog        81.8
horse    1006.1
Name: weight, dtype: float64
```

Checking if any of these are `NaN`

```
$ df.groupby(['species'])['weight'].sum().isna()

species
cat      False
dog      False
horse    False
Name: weight, dtype: bool
```